# React PropTypes - OneOf list of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I have the following array:

```
export const VALID_LANGUAGES = [
  { label: "English", value: "en" },
  { label: "French", value: "fr" },
  { label: "Italian", value: "it" },
  { label: "Portuguese", value: "pt" },
  { label: "Spanish", value: "sp" },
];
```

And I want to make sure that a component receive, as a prop "language", one of these values. How can I do it?

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  language: PropTypes.oneOf(VALID_LANGUAGES).isRequired, // Doesn't work :( 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to map the array to a list of valid language entries. The `label` property seems like the value you want.

```
language: PropTypes.oneOf(VALID_LANGUAGES.map(({ label }) => label).isRequired
```

If you instead want the language code just map the value.

```
language: PropTypes.oneOf(VALID_LANGUAGES.map(({ value }) => value).isRequired
```

## UPDATE

Actually, I just tested your original code and it also works. Each value is validated until the last option "Klingon" which is invalid and a proptypes error is logged. Here's a codesandbox demo:

[image: Edit react-proptypes-oneof-list-of-objects]

```
const VALID_LANGUAGES = [
  { label: "English", value: "en" },
  { label: "French", value: "fr" },
  { label: "Italian", value: "it" },
  { label: "Portuguese", value: "pt" },
  { label: "Spanish", value: "sp" }
];

const MyComponent = ({ language }) => <div>Language: {language.label}</div>;
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  language: PropTypes.oneOf(VALID_LANGUAGES).isRequired
};

export default function App() {
  const [language, setLanguage] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <select onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)} value={language}>
        <option value={-1} disabled>
          Select a Language
        </option>
        {VALID_LANGUAGES.map((language, index) => (
          <option key={language.value} value={index}>
            {language.label}
          </option>
        ))}
        <option value={-1}>Klingon</option>
      </select>

      <MyComponent language={VALID_LANGUAGES[language]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Perhaps you can clarify what and/or how your code isn't working.